Child Element's Negative Margin Ignored When Parent Has Zero Padding, Due to Collapsing Margin?
I'm encountering an issue with CSS where a child element's negative margin is ignored when the parent element has zero padding, which I'm learning might have something to do with
collapsing margins. Adding even a minimal padding to the parent (e.g., 0.03px) resolves the issue, but this feels like a hack. I would like confirmation if this has got to do with "collapsing margin" please. Thanks.
Example :


<br>
<br>
<br>
<div style="padding-top: 0; background-color: red;">
  <div style="margin-top: -5px;">Child Content</div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<div style="padding-top: 0.03px; background-color: red;">
  <div style="margin-top: -5px;">Child Content</div>
</div>





Yes, that's collapsing margins.
